# PlayStore reported Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption Error but i have to use static key, iv and salt

Tags: android, encryption, key, salt

PlayStore reported Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption Error because i'm using static key, iv and salt. but i have to use the static key, iv and salt because the encryption result should be the same in other platform.

I am looking for the solution in Google but it seems there is no any solution for this case. Please help me.

Comment: Can you paste the entire error here. Also what are you using for encryption kindly provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with XML file.
I stored encryption key, salt and iv after encoding them with Base64.

res/raw/config.properties

```
secret_key=VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIDEzIGxhenkgZG9ncy4=
salt=PYSiYA==
iv=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

java code

```
private String getConfigValue(Context context, String name) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        try {
            InputStream rawResource = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.config);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(rawResource);
            return properties.getProperty(name);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

Base64.decode(getConfigValue(context, "secret_key"), Base64.DEFAULT));
Base64.decode(getConfigValue(context, "salt"), Base64.DEFAULT));
Base64.decode(getConfigValue(context, "iv"), Base64.DEFAULT));
```